# I'm trying to integrate disqus in my project but ended with error

Tags: django, disqus

**the error I've got is :**
*RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.*

My setting file is like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'disqus',


]
SITE_ID = 1

 DISQUS_API_KEY = 'kLA0JWWljFwKTHvSym2oSRIlBSDCZZmReyx9NeIzPz48rtwS6Ew2vVewmZgupsea'
 DISQUS_WEBSITE_SHORTNAME = 'foobar'
```

Comment: please, could you tell what you've already tried ? (like executing `migrate` ...)

Comment: according to docs, i haven't performed the migrations yet. Should I do that?

Comment: for the contrib.sites part :  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework